# Changing MXD to relative links in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, link

I have an mxd file with absolute file pathways. The pathway of each file points to a specific location on C:. Now, I want to change to relative pathways so that the map and files can be moved to a different location without having to redirect all the pathways. The internal structure of the main folder will be identical, it's just that it won't be stored on C:.

However, when I click on relative pathways under Map Document Properties nothing seems to happen. The file pathways still points towards C:.

To be clear, the links can't point towards C: since other people won't be able to connect to my local harddrive. The links need to relative to the map location.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to reload all the data in your .mxd after you changed the settings in Document properties?

Comment: It will work. Move somewhere to test.

Comment: Jelle: I tried with one file and the C: is still there in the pathway.

Comment: FelixIP: I will try that when I'm back at work on Monday. I will have to try it on a computer that has no access to my C:.

Comment: I have updated my OP wit a clarification: "To be clear, the links can't point towards C: since other people won't be able to connect to my local harddrive. The links need to relative to the map location."

Comment: There are a number of Python tools for making paths relative. You need to provide the code you are using for us to tell what is going wrong.

Comment: @Linebeck Its tricky with the relative paths. I've seen the same thing you describe. Here is how I've corrected it. I made a folder connection to the unc path (or relative path that you want to use) in arcCatalog. Ex. \\computername\c$\folder. Then I right clicked on the mxd and used Set Data Source. I then selected one layer and then selected replace all. Update the replace with, using the \\computername\c$\. Make a copy of the map document (so as to not overwrite the original until you are ready to). Open the copy and you'll see the \\computername\c$\ for the data source of the layers.